# how can I specify a range of dates for publication_date in the News collection of IBM Watson Discovery?

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi, watson-discovery

I am transitioning our app (a few days late, unfortunately) from Alchemy News to the Watson Discovery News collection. In AN I was able to specify news that was published in a specific range of dates, but I can't figure out how to do that in WDN. I can specify a particular date, but it doesn't allow a range.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the range operators: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/query-operators.html#comparisons

Basically you can do a query like `filter=publication_date>2018-01-14`

Comment: I tried that, but I was representing the date as a string and got an error.  It does work as you said without quotes on the date. That is counter-intuitive to me.  Thanks!